# Please help me in my home networking system

Tags: wireless-networking

How can i make the devices behind router 3 ping-able and connectable with devices behind router 2?

DHCP is running on both router 2 and 3.

My network image is attached.

[image: network image]

The Screenshot of the menu is attached

[Static routing menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hX96.png)

Comment: I didn't understand ?! 2 ISP? why and how! and what about the gateway? where is your main router here, please make it more clear

Comment: If this is possible highly depends on the routers you are using.

Comment: My main router is router 2

Answer (score 0):

If thats possible highly depends on the routers you are using.

The best way would be to **create a static route** between those routers. But that's usually only possible with enterprise routers.

Another way would be to change the **subnet** from 255.255.255.0 to **255.255.254.0**. This would result in a **Class B network**, which again is usually not supported by "casual routers". With **255.255.254.0** you would have an IP-Range of **192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.254** (Broadcast 192.168.1.255)

In both ways you should set the **other router** as **gateway**. So for PCs on router 2 it would be 192.168.1.1 and for PCs on router 3 this would be 192.168.0.2

And don't forget to adjust your firewalls (on your routers and clients) accordingly...

Another way would be to have one PC acting as bridge.

For that you would need **two network adapters** installed on that PC. It doesn't matter what kind of network adapters those are - but you need to connect one adapter to router 2 and the other one to router 3.

Now on your network connections you **mark both connections** (ctrl + click those connections), followed by a **right-click** and select **bridge connections**

Now you can configure that network bridge like a normal network adapter. I would highly suggest to give that bridge a **static IP**.

On all clients the gateway would now be that PC.

Comment: Can you say how can i set up static routes?? I can see a advanced routing menu with static routes option.

Comment: Again, this depends on your router. You can find some information on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_routing Please also note, that I've added the network bridge. Thats usually the easiest way of connection two different IP ranges.

Comment: If you provide a screenshot of your router interface I might be able to tell you what to fill in. But usually those menus are quite easy to handle :)

Comment: Why are you using the WAN link within the premises OP, surely a better config would be 1 router 1 ap and 1 repeating AP unless you have a very specific need to subdivide the network.

Comment: I have added the screenshot in my question

Comment: Destination network = 192.168.1.1 on router 2, 192.168.0.1/2 (not sure) on router 3. Subnet = 255.255.255.0, Gateway = router 2 192.168.1.1 router 3 192.168.0.2 - That's how I'd give it a try :)

Comment: I can't keep running a PC for the whole day. It is very costly. Please how can i do the static routes i want to use that.

Comment: I wrote you a comment about the setup...

Answer (score 0):

Again depending on the routers you could create a VPN within the local networks?

ASUS routers allow it to be a VPN server and VPN client, you could also use a NAS synology box that has VPN server/client capabilities. That should then allow you to ping both like they were physically in the same network? That would be easier than setting up routing as if you are using a WAN I assume they are physically located elsewhere?

If they are located close to one another why could you not use the same IP pool?

Ideally more info on your setup would be great, why are they connected via a WAN?

Comment: There are two ISP which i want to use simultaneously. So to divide the networks and DHCP, i have done this.

Comment: I reckon then you may want to get yourself an ASUS router... http://www.asus.com/us/support/Search-Result-Detail/EAF00A7E-3FB9-4753-86F9-F0C6485C5C56/?keyword=dual%20wan

This will let you do what you want to achieve using the one set of DHCP pool of addresses. Then you just use the DNS settings on your clients to send them to the correct ISP?

Comment: To better help visualise what I mean... And you can specific on the router which clients go where: http://www.techpoy.com/2014/11/asus-rt-ac68u-dual-wan-set-up.html